# facebook login wiht use facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0 connect timed out

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem for facebook login with use `facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0`. This is the error:

> Type: Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException
>
> Message: connect() timed out!
>
> Filename: /home/etekcitizen/www/application/home/libraries/facebook/php-sdk-v4-5/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php
>
> Line Number: 83
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/etekcitizen/www/application/home/libraries/facebook/php-sdk-v4-5/src/Facebook/FacebookClient.php
>   Line: 216
>   Function: send
>
> File: /home/etekcitizen/www/application/home/libraries/facebook/php-sdk-v4-5/src/Facebook/Authentication/OAuth2Client.php
>   Line: 277
>   Function: sendRequest
>
> File: /home/etekcitizen/www/application/home/libraries/facebook/php-sdk-v4-5/src/Facebook/Authentication/OAuth2Client.php
>   Line: 226

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the calling code?

Comment: That is a network issue on your server – ask the admin to look into it.

Comment: hi this is calling code:

Comment: hi, this is calling code:

Comment: if(isset($_GET['code']))
     {
      $code=$_GET['code'];
      $redirectUrl=$this->base_url.'/oauth/fc_redirect';
      $fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => '167554280258086',
        'app_secret' => '8f7abd73ecc4ba07297385323ad33eb5',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
        ]);
      
      $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
      
      try {
       $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken($redirectUrl,$code);
       var_dump($accessToken);
      } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $